# Slick query for one to optional one (zero or one) relationship

Tags: sql, jdbc, slick

Given tables of:

```
case class Person(id: Int, name: String)
case class Dead(personId: Int)
```

and populated with:

```
Person(1, "George")
Person(2, "Barack")
Dead(1)
```

is it possible to have a single query that would produce a list of `(Person, Option[Dead])` like so?

```
(Person(1, "George"), Some(Dead(1)))
(Person(2, "Barack"), None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For slick 3.0 it should be something like this:

```
val query = for {
  (p, d) <- persons joinLeft deads on (_.id === _.personId)
} yield (p, d)

val results: Future[Seq[(Person, Option[Dead])]] = db.run(query.result)
```

In slick, outer joins are automatically wrapped in an `Option` type. You can read more about joining here: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#joining-and-zipping

Comment: Many thanks @Roman. Here's a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714031/tuple-hell-with-many-slick-joins